# Understanding assembly .long directive

Tags: c, assembly

In Secure programming cookbook for C and C++ from John Viega I met the following statement

```
asm("value_stored:    \n"
    ".long 0xFFFFFFFF \n"
);
```

I do not really understand the use of `.long` directive in assembly, but here it is used to embed a precalculated value in the executable. Can I somehow force the position of these bytes in the executable? I have tried to put it at the end of `main` (thinking that this way will be at the end of `.text` section), but I got segmentation fault. Putting it outside the main works.

Comment: well in C you do `long value_stored = 0xFFFFFFFF;` this is the same.

Comment: @UmNyobe: not at all the same thing.  `static unsigned long const value_stored = 0xFFFFFFFF;` does something close, as long as you jump around it as explained by AkiSuihkonen.

Answer (score 3):

Even at the end of `main` the inline assembler sequence will generate code to be executed. In my environment `objdump -d foo.o` shows:

```
00000000004004b4 <main>:
  4004b4:   55                      push   %rbp
  4004b5:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp

00000000004004b8 <value>:
  4004b8:   ff                      (bad)  
  4004b9:   ff                      (bad)  
  4004ba:   ff                      (bad)  
  4004bb:   ff                      (bad)  
  4004bc:   b8 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%eax
  4004c1:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  4004c2:   c3                      retq
```

This can be mitigated by jumping over it

```
asm("jmp 1f"
    "value: .long 0xffffffff"
    "1:");
```

Keywords Nf or Nb create local temporary labels to jump forward or backwards.

Another option will be to place the variable to a named segment, which can be sorted in the linker file as the last segment in either .text or .data.

Comment: What is the purpose of `f` in `jmp 1f`?

Comment: It's for _forward_ declaration of label `1:`.

Comment: How do you ensure proper alignment for `value`? does using `.long` make it implicit?

Comment: As the OP mentioned, you can also put it outside of any function.  Then you have a global variable and don't need to worry about jumping over it.  Gcc refers to this as "top level" asm.

Comment: @chqrlie: That has to be done explicitly with `.align 4`, causing variable length `nop` instruction(s) to be inserted.

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen I don't believe that's quite right.  The gnu assembler [docs](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Align.html#Align) say "For other systems, including i386 [...], it is the number of low-order zero bits the location counter must have after advancement. For example `.align 3` advances the location counter until it a multiple of 8."  So I assume that to properly align a long, you'd use `.align 2`.  Which just seems weird.

Comment: I tried with `.align 8` and got aligned to `4004c0:` not to `400500`.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd : your [...] snipped out an important piece "For other systems, including ppc, i386 **using a.out format**" . _GCC_ will generally output ELF format (even though the default file name generated is called `a.out`) . Since Aki is likely emitting ELF, then align will be alignment specified in bytes.  GCC can be overridden to output other formats using the linker option `-Wl,--oformat=`